# How to pass multiple strings into function to process

Tags: c

i just started C programming and im trying to do an exercise in which you read several strings in (main) into a function where it finds word and character length in each string and from (main) print the word count and character count in each string. Im not exactly sure how to do this. for example..

```
#include <stdio.h>
void convert(char s[]), int counts[]);

int main(void)
{
     char text1[] = "this IS a String 4 you."; 
     char text2[] = "This sample has less than 987654321 leTTers."
     char text3[] = "Is thIs a string?  (definitely)"


void convert(char s[]), int counts[])
{
    """code that reads each string and counts words and characters returning
    an array of characters like a[] = {3,5} each number telling how many words
    and characters the string has"""
}
```

Comment: How about add more input parameters for function?

Comment: Delete the extra `)` first.

Comment: Why? Create on function counting words in one string (returning one int). Create another one counting characters in one string (also returning one int). And then loop over your strings and call those functions.

Comment: Read about a list of pointers, e.g. `char *p[] = {"str1", "str2", "str3"};`. Then you have 2 choices. Either pass `p` in the function which will do the entire job, or better still use a `for` loop to pass strings individually into a function that returns the character and word cound. In the first case, your function accepts an array of pointers, while in the second case, it accepts a pointer to a string. Is that your question? 

BTW, Why do I feel like you just migrated to C from Python?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 char text1[] = "this IS a String 4 you."; 
 char text2[] = "This sample has less than 987654321 leTTers."
 char text3[] = "Is thIs a string?  (definitely)"
```

you can write

```
 char* texts[] = { "this IS a String 4 you.", 
                   "This sample has less than 987654321 leTTers.",
                   "Is thIs a string?  (definitely)",
                   NULL };
```

your function could look like this (C99)

```
void convert(char* s[], int counts[])
{
   for (int i = 0; s[i] != NULL; ++i)
   {
     ...do something with s[i]... 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two dimensional array. like

```
#include <stdio.h>
void convert(char s[]), int counts[]);

int main(void)
{
     char text1[][] = {"this IS a String 4 you.","This sample has less than 987654321 leTTers.","Is thIs a string?  (definitely)",NULL};

}

void convert(char s[][], int counts[])
{
    You can access here s[0][0],s[1][0],s[2][0],... etc.
    """code that reads each string and counts words and characters returning
    an array of characters like a[] = {3,5} each number telling how many words
    and characters the string has"""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void convert(char s[], int counts[])
{
     int l=0, w=0;

     for(;s[l]!='\0';l++)
         if(l!=0 && s[l]==' ' && s[l-1]!=' ')
             w++;             

     if(s[l-1]!=' ')
         w++; 

     counts[0]=l;
     counts[1]=w;

     return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to pass all the strings at once you simply modify the arguments in your function declaration and call accordingly:

```
void convert(char [], char [], char []);

int main(void)
{
    char text1[] = "some text1";
    char text2[] = "some text2";
    char text3[] = "some text3";

    convert(text1, text2, text3);
}
```

However, a possibly more reasonable way would be to store pointers to the strings and use a loop to call the conversion function for each string separately:

```
void convert(char []);

int main(void)
{
    char *texts[] = "some text1", "some text2", "some text3";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        convert(texts[i]);
    }
}
```

As for the word/character counts, you have a number of options. Just to name a few:

- pass a single value or multiple by reference to be modified by the conversion function and store the result(s) somewhere in your main function
- return the counted value(s) from your conversion function in some form (struct might be a good option for multiple values) and store it/them